# What causes my loss curve to consistently oscillate when training an LLM?

Tags: deep-learning, training, data-preprocessing, large-language-models, training-datasets

[image: loss curve]

Why is my loss curve consistently oscillating? Every 50 steps it jumps back up. I'm assumming there's a bug in my data, since I'm using [this colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1BiQiw31DT7-cDp1-0ySXvvhzqomTdI-o?usp=sharing) that shows a proper train/loss at the bottom. The only thing I changed was the dataset used. I'm using the [falcon-7b-sharded-bf16](https://huggingface.co/ybelkada/falcon-7b-sharded-bf16) huggingface model.

Comment: probably stepsize scheduling?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the colab notebook that you used, the periodic oscillation of the training loss does not seem to originate from the learning rate scheduler which is set to "constant".
However, I found that setting `group_by_length=True` [(link)](https://huggingface.co/transformers/v4.9.0/main_classes/trainer.html) in the trainer can result in periodic oscillation of the training loss.

Below are 2 training loss examples for the same model/same dataset finetuned with:
[image: group_by_length=True][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiD2j.png)
`group_by_length=True`

[image: group_by_length=False][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80aXr.png)
`group_by_length=False`